# Get key of the value based on a condition from unnamed nested array of objects in Mongo DB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document structures like this :

```js
    {
      "_id": xxxxx,
      "Name": "John Doe",
      "Grades":[
        {
        "Physics":89,
        },
        {
          "Math":45
        },
        {
          "Chemistry":57
        }
      ]
    }
```

I would like to project grades as an array of only the subjects that have over 60.

I tried this but this didn't work:

```
$arrayElemAt: [{ $objectToArray: { $gte: ['$hhEthGrp',60] } }, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need `$objectToArray` to access a values for unknown keys but you also need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) for outer array and [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) along with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to determine where there's any value for unknown key which has value over `60`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            Grades: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Grades",
                    cond: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { kv: { $objectToArray: "$$this" } }
                            in: {
                                $anyElementTrue: {
                                    $map: {
                                        input: "$$kv.v",
                                        in: {
                                            $gt: [ "$$this", 60 ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JE5ENIHLO96)